# Arithmetic operations on all elements of list

Tags: scala, list, math

I would ask how to perform arithmetic oparations on list.

substraction, division, multiplication

```
private def arithmeticOperations(leavesValues: List[Double]): Double = {
  op match {
    case '+' => leavesValues.sum
    case '-' => 0.0
    case '*' => 0.0
    case '/' => 0.0
    case _ => 0.0
  }
}
```

Zeros should be replaced by operation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private def arithmeticOperations(leavesValues: List[Double]): Double = {
  op match {
    case '+' => leavesValues.reduce(_ + _)
    case '-' => leavesValues.reduce(_ - _)
    case '*' => leavesValues.reduce(_ * _)
    case '/' => leavesValues.reduce(_ / _)
    case _ => 0.0
  }
}
```